# Как передать map в шаблонную функцию

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как передать map в качестве аргумента шаблонной функции? В функцию передается 2 параметра(первый - map, одним из параметров которого является шаблонный параметр функции, в которую он передается), вторым является ключ для map(тоже шаблонный параметр функции). Вопрос в том, как объявить второй шаблонный параметр для map

Comment: Брр... Изобразите кодом, что вы хотите, а то что-то на словах лично я запутался...

Comment: @Harry , Чтоб функцию test можно было использовать так: map<int, string> a;  auto temp = test(a, 5);   функция test является шаблонной, и возвращайт шаблонный тип данных, как объявить ее, чтоб возможно было передать map с разными типами данных,а не только одним, указанным в шаблоне функции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<typename Key, typename Val>
void foo( std::map<Key,Val> argument1, Key agrument2 )
{ ... }
```